# How to access all elements of boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<> by their indices?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using `boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<>`

Following is my container declaration:

```
typedef boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<
  myClssPtr,
  boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
    OrderdBValue //  OrderdBValue  this is boost::multi_index::ordered_unique type
  >
>
```

I want to access all the elements of this container sequentially, How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question of course, is in what order. But let me assume the most straight forward interpretation:

```
typedef boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<
  myClssPtr,
  boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
    OrderdBValue //  OrderdBValue  this is boost::multi_index::ordered_unique type
  >
> container;

for(myClassPtr& e : container.get<0>())
{
    // e.g.:
    std::cout << e << "\n";
}
```

In fact, seeing that you have only one index, this is also the default (first) index, so you can even just say

```
for(myClassPtr& e : container)
{
    // e.g.:
    std::cout << e << "\n";
}
```

**UPDATE** For c++03 the syntax is a bit more clumsy:

```
typedef employee_set::nth_index<0>::type idx_type;
for(idx_type::iterator it=container.get<0>().begin(); it != container.get<0>().end(); ++it)
{
     // e.g.
     std::cout << *it << "\n";
}
```

Now, if you /meant/ _insertion order, then you explicitly need to add e.g. `indexed_by<sequenced<> >` or `indexed_by<random_access<> >`

- See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#seq_indices

Comment: Hello @sehe, it results into folllowing error: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘:’ token, How ":" will work in for loop?

Comment: Use the regular, but with c++03 syntax: **Updated** answer (of course, time to upgrade your compiler, or pass `-std=c++11`!)

Comment: See [Iterator Access](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#iterator_access) in the documentation